# scrollbar on inner div with height 100%

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a sidebar with header(with few tabs) and a content - form. I wish to have scrollbar on that form whenever the page is shrunk in a way that form content is not completely visible.

My problem is that scrollbar appears too late and it is because of the header. I am boiling my head for hours, but I can't make it work. I have posted similar question yesterday, only without that header div, It worked I just can't make work this scenario.

My approach so far is:

html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="tabheader">tab header...</div>
  <div id="formdiv">
    <form id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <label>Dropdown 1
        <select id="select1"></select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Dropdown 2
        <select id="select2"></select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Dropdown 3
        <select id="select3"></select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Dropdown 4
        <select id="select4"></select>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

div#tabheader {
  display: table;
  border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}

div#formdiv {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

select {
  width: 300px;
}
```

[And JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kefahuchi/wxyuLh5h/)

When I remove that header div everything works well.

Note: For my needs **sidebar must have position fixed**. I will prefer solution that not rely on knowing header height, if there is any such a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `#formdiv` is 100% height so it becames bigger than its parent itself. If you know the height of the `#tabheader`, for example in the jsfiddle the height is 24px, so when you change the height of the `#formdiv` to `height: calc(100% - 24px);` it's working properly.

Comment: thank you for your effort, I thought of that, but I will prefer a solution without knowing height of the tab header, if there is any...I should probably updated that question with it.

Comment: So far I haven't found solution that works without knowing header height in advance. Finally I am getting header height by javaScript and setting style with calc, as you advised. Since I haven't found anything better and your calc hint helped, I am marking as answered...